# Django Rest Framework, can I use ViewSet to generate a json from django view function?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I know I can use drf serializer from django views, but queryset, pagination setting is all duplicated in drf viewset and django view.

Can I reuse viewset to generate json data and include it in regular django response?

**Update:**
ie, Can I call `ViewSet.as_view()(self.request)` from django view?
it's not documented way, so I'm wondering the downsides of this approach .. and if it's doable..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call YourViewSet.as_view()(self.request) in your Django view.

Make sure you call the ViewSet like below:

> YourViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(self.request)

Else it will raise an exception

> The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`